# search text in beginning of word

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select rows which hold certain text('one') only in a beginning of a word in a certain field (name). 
Example: 
1)name : name one check 
2)name : name anotherone check 
I only need row number 1.
I am currently using LIKE %one% ,get those results(rows 1 and 2, more then I need), I then check if the text is located in the beginning of a word or not and keep the results I need.
is there a way to run a query which will break the values in name field according to specific chars (lets say: " "), and then check each Piece if the text is located in the beginning of it?

Comment: How about just `LIKE '% one%' OR LIKE 'one%'`?

Comment: Tnx Kristen. so simple...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the Like Operator: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE name LIKE 'one%'`

(don't use `%` on both sides as this will find `ANYTHINGoneANYTHING`.)

However, If the word can appear somewhere in the sentence, you need the double `%`:
Add a whitespace, like this: `LIKE '% one%'` to ensure the word STARTS with "one".
If the word needs to be standalone, you can use `LIKE '% one %'` (this however will not match The start or end of the field. It will fail on `one test`.)

To bypass this problem, you can concatenate the field with a leading and trailing whitespace:

`... WHERE CONCATENATE(" ", CONCATENATE (field, " ")) LIKE '% one %'`

This will match `Theres one`, `one goes home` and even `if there is one that goes home`, but not `someone is there` or `hes done`.